# How to change tool tip using High Charts

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, tooltip

I have successfully created a chart using High Chart to compare the expected time & arrival time of a patient.

However, I am now having an issue with the `label` of the columns; which is displaying time in `milliseconds`.

The screen shot below shows the issue:

[image]

How do I change the label to display time in format (H:M:S)

CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function drawChart(){
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'divforchart',
                    type:'column',
                },
                xAxis: {
                    name:'patients',
                    categories: [<?php
                    echo "'".$names[0]."'";
                    for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($names); $i++){
                        echo ",'".$names[$i]."'";
                    }
                    ?>]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                        //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
                        second: '%H:%M:%S',
                        minute: '%H:%M:%S',
                        hour: '%H:%M:%S',
                        day: '%H:%M:%S',
                        week: '%H:%M:%S',
                        month: '%H:%M:%S',
                        year: '%H:%M:%S'
                    },
                    min: <?php echo "Date.UTC(".gmdate("Y,m,d,H",strtotime($minDate)).")";?>
                },

                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Arrival time',
                        data: [<?php
                            echo "['".$names[0]."',Date.UTC(".gmdate("Y,m,d,H,i,s",strtotime($Arrival_time[0])).")]";
                            for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($names); $i++){
                                echo "
                                ,['".$names[$i]."',Date.UTC(".gmdate("Y,m,d,H,i,s",strtotime($Arrival_time[$i])).")]";
                            }
                        ?>]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Expected time',
                        data: [<?php
                            echo "['".$names[0]."',Date.UTC(".gmdate("Y,m,d,H,i,s",strtotime($Expected_time[0])).")]";
                            for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($names); $i++){
                                echo "
                                ,['".$names[$i]."',Date.UTC(".gmdate("Y,m,d,H,i,s",strtotime($Expected_time[$i])).")]";
                            }
                        ?>]
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="drawChart()">
     <div id="divforchart" style="height: 400px"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of it, you are referring to the tooltip, not the dataLabel.
You can use the formatter function to format the date properly:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

(if you are in fact talking about the dataLabel, you can do the same thing still: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter )

I think the default is to numberFormat the y axis value, but you will want to instead use the dateFormat function in your formatter:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29

If you need help implementing, create a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) and post back

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is the tool tip, not the data label. Although, I am not sure where this functionality is or how to edit it?

Comment: Details are in the example linked to in my answer.  Take a look here too: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/289/

Comment: In my code, I don't think tool tip has been specified as I cant see it anywhere but the tool tip is clearly working?

Comment: tooltip is enabled by default and has default formatting established.

Comment: Okay, where shall I add this; tooltip:{
        formatter:function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.y);
        }

Comment: I've given you links to the docs, and they link to examples of charts.  I've given you an example that uses your exact scenario.  All you have to do is look at those examples :) It's spelled out pretty clearly...

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat(values)
```

See here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat%28%29

This if you want it in the serie, or you can change the tooltip.

```
series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter:function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.y);
            },
            style:{color:"black"}
        },
        data: [data]
    }]
```

Tooltip:

```
tooltip:{
    formatter:function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S',this.y);
    }
}
```

Your code must look like:

```
chart: {
                    renderTo: 'divforchart',
                    type:'column',
                },
tooltip: { ...
```

Comment: I inserted your code as suggested, but once executed the chart does not show at all.

Comment: Remove color: colors[0], I declare colors as a var in my code, I edit my answer. Or check your console with F12 and see the error.